# Custom element in repeater not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to display some data in a repeater, and I can't get it to work.

```
<dom-module id="mythings-latest-values">
    <template>
        <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[mythings]]">
                <li>X <mythings-list-item item="{{item}}"></mythings-list-item></li>
                <li>[[item.length]] [[((item.length)-1)]] {{item[item.length-1].code}}: [[item[item.length-1].price]]</li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </template>

    <script>
        class MythingsLatestValues extends ReduxMixin(Polymer.Element) {
            static get is() { return 'mythings-latest-values'; }
            static get properties() {
                return {
                    mythings: {
                        type: Object,
                        statePath(state) {
                            return Object.values(state.mythings);
                        }
                    },
                };
            }

            ready() {
                console.log("ready: ",this.item);
            }
        }

        window.customElements.define(MythingsLatestValues.is, MythingsLatestValues);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

and:

```
<dom-module id="mythings-list-item">
    <template>
        AA
    </template>

    <script>
        class MythingsListItem extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'mythings-list-item'; }

        }
        window.customElements.define(MythingsListItem.is, MythingsListItem);
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

As output, my list looks like:

- X
- 1 [[((item.length)-1)]] {{item[item.length-1].code}}: [[item[item.length-1].price]]

The logic in the data binding in the template clearly doesn't work, so instead I moved it to a separate element: mythings-list-item. It runs. When I give it a ready() method with some logging, that runs only once (rather than for every item), but it doesn't display at all.

What's going on here?

I only just started using Polymer. It's entirely possible I'm overlooking something really basic, but I just don't see it.

I'm using polymer-redux, also new to me, but I don't see how it can cause this problem, although it could be responsible for my missing data. If so, that's a separate issue and outside the scope of my question. I'm just trying to get the template with the repeater working.

Edit: I found the answer (see below). Turns out I forgot to call `super.ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: my ready() method doesn't call `super.ready();`. Adding that fixes it.

New ready() method:

```
ready() {
    super.ready();
    console.log("ready: ",this.item);
}
```

I suspect every life cycle callback needs to call super.

Answer (score 0):

Demo : [Polymer-2.0-Redux](https://github.com/whip8466/Polymer-2.0-Redux)

make sure `mythings-list-item.html` and `redux-state.html`(where you set redux sture) is imported or not?

set value of properties like `return state.mythings` and if you want to check data is coming or not from redux use `observer`.

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        mythings: {
            type: Object,
            statePath(state) {
                return state.mythings;
            },
            observer: "_checkMythings(mythings)"
        },
    };
}

_checkMythings(mythings){
    console.log(mythings);
}
```

Comment: Yes, everything is imported and data from redux is flowing. My problem turned out to be that I included a ready() function that didn't call super.ready(). Failing to call super apparently breaks rendering.

Comment: I added `Demo : Polymer-2.0-Redux` in my answer. go through code, It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

how `mythings` property will repeat? since it is an object. It should be array.